# How to make a PictureBox scrollable?

Tags: c#, picturebox

On my form i have a PictureBox inside Panel.
I set:

```
MyPanel.AutoScroll = true
MyPictureBox.SizeMode = AutoSize
```

After i add image into PictureBox:

```
MyPictureBox.Image = Image.FromFile(path);
```

But when i open form i don't see any scrollbars inside.
What can be wrong?

Comment: I should work. Is the Image really larger than the Panel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to probably set height and width of PictureBox and set AutoScroll property of Panel to true.

```
Panel MyPanel = new Panel();
PictureBox pictureBox1 = new PictureBox();

Image image = Image.FromFile("image.png");

pictureBox1.Image = image;
pictureBox1.Height = image.Height;
pictureBox1.Width = image.Width;

MyPanel.Controls.Add(pictureBox1);
MyPanel.AutoScroll = true;
this.Controls.Add(MyPanel);
```

Comment: Make that `pictureBox1.ClientSize = image.Size;`

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
MyPanel.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.Auto
```

Comment: I cant find a `Panel` property in `System.Window.Forms.Panel`.

Comment: Hi Kilver Max, the panel is added to the GUI designer manually. Toolbox->Containers->Panel. 

What we are doing is:
(1) Put a Panel onto our Window
(2) Put a PictureBox in the Panel
(3) Configure ScrollBars via the Panel's properties

Answer (score 1):

Tips:

1. Verify that `MyPictureBox` is inside `MyPanel`, in other words, `MyPanel` contains `MyPictureBox`.
2. On the **Designer**, make `MyPictureBox` significantly smaller than its container `MyPanel`. Due to `AutoSize`, it will fill the entire space provided by the container during runtime.
3. Check that `MyPictureBox` has property `Anchor` set to `Top, Left` but NOT `Top, Left, Bottom, Right`.